# Token caching mechanism when using OAuth bearer tokens and OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions in ASP.NET Web Api 2

Tags: oauth, asp.net-web-api2, openid, claims-based-identity, bearer-token

Inside my startup.auth.cs I do:

```
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication()
```

And I feed it an OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions with a bunch of options tailored to using an Azure Active Directory B2C tenant.  This by itself is functioning well.  I am able to login with my MVC app, acquire a bearer token and make calls to this Web Api 2 project and I see a valid authenticated Identity.  All is well.

However what I need to do is do a little more work in the validation process and add some custom claims to the identity.  I am trying to figure out where the best place is to do that.  For example, in my MVC app using OpenID, I can use the OnSecurityTokenValidated notification of the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions to add claims.  This new token/identity with my new claims seem to be cached somewhere throughout the mysterious vastness of OWIN such that the identity of subsequent calls have my extra added claims without having to go through OnSecurityTokenValidated every single time.

For the OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions counterpart, I tried adding claims in ValidateIdentity() of a custom OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider.  This works, but I don't want to incur the performance hit every single time a call comes in because this callback is hit every single time, not just once during token validation.

So my question is if there is some place throughout all the Oauth Bearer token classes and OWIN middleware stuff where I can do this that is similar to ValidateToken() for the OpenID counterpart, or do I have to write my own caching mechanism?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Facing the same issue